# CaseDetection macro in Swift 5.9 & Xcode15

Tags: swift, xcode15

The @CaseDetection macro discussed in the ["What's new in Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10164) (15:22) WWDC2023 seems really useful. @CaseDetection is not a recognized in XCode 15 release. It wasn't defined in the presentation so it led to think that it was included but that doesn't appear to be the case given the Xcode error.

How does one get access to @CaseDetection and, also @Observable?

Update (10/4/2023) illustrating problems:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: 10/5/2023
I finally got it to work but I did need to add the CaseDetectionPlugin to CaseDetectionMacro like this:

```
@main 
struct CaseDetectionPlugin: CompilerPlugin { 
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [CaseDetectionMacro.self,]
}
```

I also feel that the declaration of the new member should be public like this:

```
public var is(raw: uppercased): Bool {
   if case .(raw: original) = self { true } else { false }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `CaseDetection` is just an example for WWDC. It's not in the standard library.

I found its implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Examples/Sources/MacroExamples/Implementation/Member/CaseDetectionMacro.swift), in the examples folder of SwiftSyntax.

> ```
> import SwiftSyntax
> import SwiftSyntaxMacros
>
> public enum CaseDetectionMacro: MemberMacro {
>   public static func expansion(
>     of node: AttributeSyntax,
>     providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
>     in context: some MacroExpansionContext
>   ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
>     declaration.memberBlock.members
>       .compactMap { $0.decl.as(EnumCaseDeclSyntax.self) }
>       .map { $0.elements.first!.name }
>       .map { ($0, $0.initialUppercased) }
>       .map { original, uppercased in
>         """
>         var is\(raw: uppercased): Bool {
>           if case .\(raw: original) = self {
>             return true
>           }
>
>           return false
>         }
>         """
>       }
>   }
> }
>
> extension TokenSyntax {
>   fileprivate var initialUppercased: String {
>     let name = self.text
>     guard let initial = name.first else {
>       return name
>     }
>
>     return "\(initial.uppercased())\(name.dropFirst())"
>   }
> }
> ```

You should put that in a separate module, and declare it like this:

```
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro CaseDetection() = #externalMacro(module: "ModuleWhereTheMacroIsImplemented", type: "CaseDetectionMacro")
```

Interestingly, this macro only generates an `isXXX` property for each `case` on a new line. It would generate `isA` for `case a, b` for example. If you want it to generate a property for cases written on the same line as well, change the line `.map { $0.elements.first!.name }` to `.flatMap { $0.elements }.map { $0.name }`.

Comment: I can't get this to work ... I create a swift macro package: CaseDetection.
Xcode created a CaseDetection folder with a file by the same name in the older. This is where the declaration goes:
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro CaseDetection() = #externalMacro(module: "CaseDetectionMacros", type: "CaseDetectionMacro")
This generates a warning: "External macro implementation type 'CaseDetectionMacros.CaseDetectionMacro' could not be found for macro 'CaseDetection()'"
It also created a CaseDetectionMacros folder with file CaseDetectionMacro for implementation. What's wrong?

Comment: @Phantom59 you should write the macro’s implementation in the CaseDetectionMacro file. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the original question with screenshots showing the folder structure and contents of each.

Comment: @Phantom59 Did you delete the `CaseDetectionPlugin` struct in the CaseDetectionMacro.swift file? It should be a struct that is autogenerated for you from the project template. You should declare your macro there too: `let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [CaseDetectionMacro.self]`.

Comment: @Phantom59 Also, apparently, the enum cases should be on separate lines for this particular implementation to generate properties for every case.

Comment: I finally got it to work but I did need to make a couple of changes; see update. Thanks! –